# Separate project for only images - need refactoring?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, refactoring, servlet-filters

I have webapp project (tomcat + jsp + spring)

I want all images move to different project. It'll give me possible to change images by redeploy only one war.

The biggest problem which I have is when I'll move images to new project I need change all paths in jsp, css files. Is there any solution without big refactoring? (maybe Filter which mapping all calling /images/* to /ProjectWithImages/images/*? Is performance good for this solution?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map a Servlet to `/images/*` and from there - get the target file as stream, and copy it to the output stream, setting all necessary headers.

Comment: but what about files which aren't on the same machine? How you can read it as stream?! I think better way is to modify all request /images/* -> /NEW_PROJECT/images/*. What do you think about it?

Comment: if they are on a different server, than you can send a `redirect` to them.